# Missing Menus Structure

Tags: menus, admin-menu

When I go to update my menu via `Appearance` → `Menus`, the "Menu Structure" on the right is completely missing. So I'm unable to update my menu. The `Pages` section is there, but no "Menu Structure".

Has anyone seen this or know what to do here?

[image: WordPress Menu Admin]

Comment: It seems you don't have any many created, just click on **Create a new menu**, add some elements to it and then mark it as primary.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `add_theme_support( 'menus' );` in `functions.php` I haven’t taken the time to investigate. I suspect it depends on what theme is being resolved and how the `functions.php` is setup. also try to disable auto fill form browser.

did you register the menu?? if not then add this to your `functions.php`

```
function my_theme_setup() {
  register_nav_menus( array( 
    'header' => 'Header menu', 
    'footer' => 'Footer menu' 
  ) );
 }

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup' );
```